# Print formatting a tuple that only has one index position

Tags: python, datetime, printing, formatting, tuples

```
my_tuple = tuple([(user,date)] for user,date in tuple_search if datetime.now() > date - timedelta(days=60))
message_text = ('You are receiving this message because your account is going to expire on {}. Please log in to reset your password.'.format(my_tuple))
print(message_text)

>>>You are receiving this message because your account is going to expire on ([(<User username:dev>, datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 10, 20, 3, 32))], [(<User username:lol>, datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 21, 17, 3, 25))]. Please log in to reset your password.
```

I would like to format the above tuple so that in each print statement it only prints out the date in the open parentheses. Something like `is going to expire on (12/10/2020)` and it would also print out the next message with a different date like `is going to expire on (1/21/2021)` I am having a problem splitting the tuple into different elements. It is currently only one element and I am not sure how I could format it to be many.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: The problem is probably with `what_user`, which you don't show us.

Comment: @PeterWood that was supposed to be `my_tuple` I have corrected it.

Comment: @Prune This code cannot be reproducible as it relies on data that is only available from an outside source. I just need  help formatting the tuple in a print statement. If I say `new_tup = [i[0] for i in my_tuple]
        print(new_tup)` , the output would be ([(<User username:dev>, datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 10, 20, 3, 32))], [(<User username:lol>, datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 21, 17, 3, 25))]

Comment: @blahblah Please just make up a small sample of data so we can test our work in an interpreter.

Comment: Again, refer to the MRE documentation: you provide a small, "sanitized" data set to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract and format the dates from the datetime, you can use an f-string and the parameters of the datetime object.

```
for elem in my_tuple:
    print(f"The expiry date for Username {elem[0][0]}\n")
    print(f" is ({elem[0][1].month}/{elem[0][1].day}/{elem[0][1].year})")
```

Which produces (in my made-up version of your `my_tuple` variable. I am more than happy to edit if you can give us a reproducible version):

```
The date for user1 
is (12/1/2020)
The date for user2 
is (12/1/2020)
```

f-strings are a nice feature that has been added in 3.6 that makes things a little more easy to read.

Comment: This is perfect! Is there anyway that you can explain how you figured out what each element each index number is? How did you know the username was [0][0] and that month was [0][1]

Comment: Your tupled comprehension is a tuple of singleton lists containing another size-two tuple. If you want to lose the first zero, change `my_tuple` to `tuple((user, date) for user, date in tuple_search ... )` or even better just ((user, date) for user, date in tuple_search ... )` although assuming you are beginner, you may want to look up how generators work first.

Comment: Also please accept this answer if it works for you.